# Get sum of all rows in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get sum of all rows in each row. Example

```
Rows | TotalCount
  1  | 20
  2  | 30
  3  | 10
  4  | 60
```

Now, I want get following result.

```
    Rows | TotalCount
      1  | 120
      2  | 120
      3  | 120
      4  | 120
```

If it is possible in SQL server please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 14):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*, sum(totalcount) over ()
from t;
```

In general, window functions are going to be faster than `join`/aggregation solutions.  This is a rather simple case, so the performance might be essentially the same.

Comment: The execution plan shows that this is slightly more efficient than the solutions by jarlh, +1.

Answer (score 4):

Use a sub-query where you do the `SUM` work:

```
select rows, (select sum(TotalCount) from tablename) as TotalCount 
from tablename
```

Or a `cross join`:

```
select t1.rows, t2.TotalCount
from tablename t1
  cross join (select sum(TotalCount) as TotalCount from tablename) t2
```

Comment: do you know if those query are equivalent and db do the optimization? to me the first looks like have to perform the subquery for every row, so second one should be better.

Comment: well I just did the test. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e2fe/2 even when the steps on the plan are in a different order look like the cost are the same

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, since the sub-query is uncorrelated, I suppose it's executed only once - in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     Rows       INT,
     TotalCount INT
  )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES      (1,
             20),
            (2,
             30),
            (3,
             10),
            (4,
             60)

DECLARE @total INT=(SELECT Sum(totalcount)
  FROM   @table)

SELECT rows,
       @total AS TotalCount
FROM   @table
```